# Django: Could not find the GDAL library (OSX)

Tags: django, postgis, gdal, geodjango, postgis-installation

After my old macbook died I am transferring across a Django Webapp I'd been building to my new machine (which is a MacBook Pro M1 2021). I am currently in the process of reinstalling the correct packages and extensions for the app.

However I am currently getting the following error when I do `python3 manage.py runserver`:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library 
(tried "gdal", "GDAL", "gdal3.3.0", "gdal3.2.0", "gdal3.1.0", 
"gdal3.0.0", "gdal2.4.0", "gdal2.3.0", "gdal2.2.0", "gdal2.1.0", "gdal2.0.0"). 
Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.
```

The database I created was through a server on Postgres.app which I believe comes [packaged up with PostGIS, GDAL etc.](https://postgis.net/install/)

I have also run `pip3 install GDAL` and `brew install GDAL`

I have tried following the [geoDjango documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/#postgres-app) and I added the following in the terminal:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/14/bin
```

When I run `which psql` it returns: `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/14/bin/psql`

I can't figure it out.

Full traceback of error:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 115, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 300, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 207, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 204, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .features import DatabaseFeatures
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/features.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.features import BaseSpatialFeatures
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/base/features.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db import models
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions  # NOQA
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/functions.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import BaseSpatialField, GeometryField
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .fields import (  # NOQA
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/fields.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALException
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/datasource.py", line 40, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/prototypes/ds.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py", line 46, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal", "GDAL", "gdal3.3.0", "gdal3.2.0", "gdal3.1.0", "gdal3.0.0", "gdal2.4.0", "gdal2.3.0", "gdal2.2.0", "gdal2.1.0", "gdal2.0.0"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay figured it out thanks to this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412950/gdal-configuration-for-django-in-mac-gdal-library-path-exception), the pertinent info for me was:

> The solution is to manually set GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH (link) and
> GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH (link) in settings.py:
>
> ```
> GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '/opt/homebrew/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.dylib'
> GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = '/opt/homebrew/opt/geos/lib/libgeos_c.dylib'
> ```

Comment: how is possible to use the GDAL version included in the postgres.app instead of homebrew's?

Comment: It's a workaround. Not a solution. What if the other devs are using a Linux machine. path "opt/homebrew/.. " does not exist for them. So you have to maintain seperate django settings for each OS type. Not a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do:

```
brew install postgis
```

After that manually set GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH and GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH  in settings.py:

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '/opt/homebrew/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.dylib'
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = '/opt/homebrew/opt/geos/lib/libgeos_c.dylib'
```

Answer (score 2):

`Postgres.app` is an application that provides a self-contained PostgreSQL database server for macOS.

The location of GDAL and GEOS library path can vary depending on the version but follows a path like `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/xxx/lib`. There `xxx` is version of postgres.app like 14, 15 accordingly.

You need to set the path manually in `settings.py` like:

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/xxx/lib/libgdal.dylib'
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = '/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/xxx/lib/libgeos_c.dylib'
```

Replace your version number instead of `xxx` for question's author it would be 14.

---

**Better alternate**

MacOS tries to locate GDAL library in standard library paths like `/usr/local/lib`, `/usr/lib` and locations in `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable so if you do not prefer adding extra code in `settings.py` you could add following to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/xxx/lib/
```